# How to print error html in alamofire in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am making api request with Alamofire.When my api failes it gives html response so alamofire return a error message as below

> Reponse  ->FAILURE: 
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}))

I tried below code

```
   Alamofire.request(absolutePath(forApi: functionName), method: apiMethod, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: defaultHeader())
            .responseJSON { result in

                DILog.print(items: "URL -> \(self.absolutePath(forApi: functionName))")
                if let _ = parameters {
                    DILog.print(items: "Parameters ->\(String(describing: parameters)) ")
                }
                DILog.print(items: "Headers ->\(self.defaultHeader()) ")
                DILog.print(items: "Reponse  ->\(result) ")
                DILog.print(items: "Reponse1  ->\(result.value) ")
                DILog.print(items: "Reponse Code ->\(result.response?.statusCode) ")

                if let errorResponse = result.error {
                    print(errorResponse.localizedDescription)
                    failure(self.parseError(error: errorResponse))
                }
}
```

I want to print the error response as html returned by API. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: try with "debugPrint(result)"

Answer (score 3):

Convert the response data into string, like below

```
if let _ = result.error {
  print("--------- Error -------")
  if let responseData = result.data {
    let htmlString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(htmlString!)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helpful for you to print response from Alamofire
https://github.com/netguru/ResponseDetective